# HP Proliant DL380 G5 Crash with dual CPU

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

About a year ago i got a fully functional HP Proliant DL380 G5 with one CPU Intel Xeon E5420 (4x 2,5GHz)
I had VMWARE ESXI installed, everything went perfect.
I bought a extra CPU, another E5420 @ 2,5GHz on eBay.
I plugged it in, and started ESXI. Purpel Crash Screen. Error code belongs to a Hardware Error. I tought i have to reinstall ESXI. Some time later, i picked up my Server again, and wanted to install ESXI. Purpel Screen, same error.
Then i wanted to install Windows Server, crash.
Then i have installed Debian, everything works (Dual CPU).
I have unplugged Proc 2 and i installed ESXI, its working, Windows Server too.

So why ESXI and Windows Server crashed at 2 CPUs?
Is the CPU broken? Should i buy 1 new CPU?
But why is Debian working with dual CPU?

Random fact: If i install one CPU, install Windows Server, and set the Processors to 4 (1 CPU) and plug the second Processor in, Windows starts and Device Manager shows 8 CPUs @ 2,5GHz. But if i start without msconfig processor limitation, crash. I have activated Windows, and switched CPUs.

Thanks.

Comment: What did HP support say?

Comment: Dont have asked them.

Comment: The vendor should always be your first point of contact for hardware issues. It's quite likely that you do indeed have a hardware problem, that will only be able to be resolved by HP. As to why the issue doesn't express itself on all OSes? Well, different software, different kernels, etc.

Comment: Server is 11 Years old i think, CPU costs about 7 dollar. I only wanted to know if i should buy a new CPU or if its a server issue.

Comment: @EEAA HP won't support a machine so far out of warranty. This is very old hardware.

Comment: @ewwhite Oh G5. Yup. That's what, circa 2009?

Comment: They were: 2005-2008

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have bad components. That could be CPU, CPU socket, motherboard or RAM.

Nobody will support such old hardware. It would be far easier to obtain a known-working replacement. [This equipment is cheap now](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HP-PROLIANT-DL380-G5-2xIntel-Xeon-Server-w-3-GHz-DVDROM-Drive-WORKING-/391667195008?hash=item5b312f1c80:g:qEQAAOSw44BYQ2k9), so try finding another unit.